# Statistical test for vector of expected values

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Two characteristics are tested on population elements $X_1$ and $X_2$.
We assume that $X = (X_1, X_2)\sim N_2 (\mu, \Sigma)$ where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are parameters. The sample size is equal to $20$. It was calculated that (for the sample)
$$
\bar x = \begin{bmatrix}0 \newline 1
         \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
s = \begin{bmatrix}
5&-3 \newline
-3&9
         \end{bmatrix}
$$
The above values are the mean and standard deviation calculated from the sample.
At the $\alpha = 0.05$ level, verify the hypothesis system:
$H_0: $ $\mu_1 = 2\mu_2$
$H_1: $ $\mu_1 \neq 2\mu_2$.
I don't know how to get down to this task. I have never encountered such an arrangement of hypotheses.

Comment: Because under the null hypothesis $Y = X_1-2X_2$ has a Normal distribution with mean $\mu_1 - 2\mu_2 = 0,$ mean, all you have to do is construct a sample of $Y$ from your data and test whether its mean is zero.

Comment: Notation issue: Your $s$ is not a standard deviation by my understanding of the meaning of the term. Please clarify what the elements of your $s$-matrix consist of (it *looks* like it might perhaps be a sample variance-covariance matrix, whence $\text{diag}(s)^\frac12$. with the square root taken element-wise, would be a vector of standard deviations; but if it's something else you should explain how $s$ is calculated).

Answer (score 8):

The problem can be solved using a slightly modified paired $t$-test in which, the null is $H_0:\mu_1 -2\mu_2 = 0$ and the alternative is $H_1:\mu_1 -2\mu_2 \neq 0$. The procedure is thus to apply a $t$ to the difference data $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$, where $Y_i = X_{1i}-2X_{2i}$, as noted by @whuber.

The test statistic is

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}\bar Y}{\sqrt{s_Y^2}}\sim t_{n-1}.$$

For this test thus you only require $s_Y^2$, the sample variance of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$, and of course, its sample average $\bar Y = \bar{X_1}-2\bar{X_2}$.

Comment: I'm confused... What prevents the OP to translate $\mu_1 = 2\mu_2$ into the equivalent $10000\mu_1 - 20000\mu_2$? Now $\bar{Y} = -20000$ which I suspect will completely destroy the test statistic value

Comment: @gota, the $t$-statistic is invariant to linear transformations. Do you see it why?

Comment: yes, but it's unclear to me exactly how to compute $s_Y$ in this case

Comment: You'd have $Y_{your} = 10^4 X_1 - 10^4\cdot 2\cdot X_2 = 10^4Y$, thus $s_{Y_{your}} = 10^4 s_Y$ and $\bar Y_{your} = 10^4 \bar Y$ and the invarinace follows.

Comment: sure, but how to compute $s_Y$ for this example?

Comment: Let $a = (1,-2)^\top$, $X$ be the $n\times 2$ data matrix and $S_X$ be the sample variance covariance matrix of $X$, e.g. what OP calls $s$. Then $s_Y^2 = a^\top S_X a$.